# Dual boot problem; How to add Windows Vista on GRUB menu?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-vista

I have a Toshiba PSAARL - 03S004.

I've installed my Window Vista on hard disk C, but there is no selection to boot into Window Vista on GRUB!

I only can boot into Ubuntu server now!

## EDIT

Result of `sudo blkid`

```
/dev/sda1/ UUID="bcbe885a-0922-40d2-9135-479677736db3" TYPE=ext2'. 
/dev/sda5 : UUID"UOgSLs-6ZTI-iojp-jpjl-2zpU-aylo-NjVZwp" TYPE=LVM2_member".
/dev/mapper/rigo--vg-root: UUID="e07cb65d-1880-41fb-bf41-fcf034c38c6d" TYPE="ext4"
```

Comment: Are you sure you installed Ubuntu alongside Windows instead of erasing Windows? Run `sudo blkid` and check your drive structure.

Comment: it said:  
/dev/sda1/ UUID="bcbe885a-0922-40d2-9135-479677736db3" TYPE=ext2'. 
/dev/sda5 : UUID"UOgSLs-6ZTI-iojp-jpjl-2zpU-aylo-NjVZwp" TYPE=LVM2_member".  
/dev/mapper/rigo--vg-root: UUID="e07cb65d-1880-41fb-bf41-fcf034c38c6d" TYPE="ext4"

Comment: I suspect you have overwritten Windows. To be sure, can you run `sudo fdisk -l`. Put the results in your question above and not in a comment please.

Answer (score 1):

Try this : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair
It saved my grub many times

Comment: How to connect to internet?

Comment: You can't connect to Internet with the live CD/USB ?